# XeLaTeX ligatures clash with package xesearch

Tags: xetex, fontspec, babel, xesearch

I am using `XeLaTeX` to compile a document in French, using the `fontspec` package (with the `Ligatures=TeX}` option) and `babel` package (with the `french` option on). The problem: the `endash` and `emdash` ligatures do not work when the `xesearch` package is loaded. Any suggestions?

```
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///xelatex/[--shell-escape]
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{xesearch}% Package clash
\begin{document}

blabla - blabla

blabla --- blabla

blabla --- blabla

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's not much you can do: `babel-french` wants to assign `-` to a particular character class and `xesearch` to another one. No way the two can coexist.

Comment: Oh that's depressing. I was using ``xesearch`` to have a wordcounter. Can I use an endash and emdash that I would copy-paste from some character list? I could then have a keyboard mapping. I am co-writing with someone who will not care for any code, -- a double-dash was already going to be a hard-sell -- so no way I can suggest ``\endash``... I guess what I'm asking is, since I'm compiling with ``XeLaTeX`` a utf-8 endash would be understood, correct? (and thanks for your comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way `xesearch` can work with `babel-french`. Both want to put `-` in a particular character class for exploiting the `\XeTeXinterchartoks` feature.

However, you can directly input the en-dash and em-dash and the result is as expected, at least in your example. But malfunctions of `xesearch` might arise, because the character class of `-` will be 0 with `babel-french` whereas `xesearch` expects it to be 254.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX} % not needed
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{xesearch}% Package clash
\begin{document}

blabla - blabla

blabla – blabla

blabla — blabla

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks egreg. How do you figure out stuff like that! Why do these packages use different classes? what is it "for"?

Comment: @PatrickT Put simply, `xesearch` is a hack that abuses the interchar tokens feature for doing different things it was thought for; `babel-french` instead uses it for typesetting, which is how it should.